# Could not find method Android.media.Mediaplayer.getPlaybackParams, Reference from method

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I just wanted to know why is this error showing . Could anyone please give me some idea it's pointing me on this direction

```
private AndroidJavaObject _pluginObj;

public float PlaybackRate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_pluginObj != null)
                return _pluginObj.Call<float>("exportGetPlaybackRate");

            return 1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_pluginObj != null)
                _pluginObj.Call("exportSetPlaybackRate", value);
        }
    }
```

I build an APK then the error on the logcat says that:

> Could not find method Android.media.Mediaplayer.getPlaybackParams, Reference from method

By the way . I bought a Unity Asset which is UMP(Universal Media Player) Pro on the Unity Asset Store. It builds successfully on the test script but when i did apply that on my project then there that error came. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came up with a new method of doing the livestream guys.